# Authorizing A Native WP7 Applications Using Facebook C# SDK

Tags: windows-phone-7, authentication, facebook-c#-sdk

I have just installed the Facebook C# SDK in my WP7 application using NuGet, so I am sure it is the latest version. However I can't seem to find any documentation for WP7 anywhere... All I am trying to do is authenticate the user using Facebook to gain their Facebook ID. Can someone please tell me how I can do this using Facebook C# SDK or link me to an article that explains this that is up to date.

Thanks,
Alex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the C# SDK's Documentation, you do the authentication using the Javascript SDK and then AJAX it to your server.

See the "Obtaining an Access Token" section of http://csharpsdk.org/docs/web/getting-started.html

Comment: This does not translate well to a mobile applications flow.

Comment: But yeah it would appear the FB C# SDK does not handle the login process for you, I found a good guide here: http://buildmobile.com/facebook-in-a-windows-phone-7-app/#fbid=j-yNY5PYF2_

Answer (score 0):

Did you see the answers at [How to get started with the Facebook C# SDK for WP7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5382473/how-to-get-started-with-the-facebook-c-sharp-sdk-for-wp7)? They seem to provide samples / examples / walkthroughs

Comment: The samples are no longer available to my knowledge.

Comment: There is WInFOrms smaples avalible at https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-winforms-sample and an ASP.NET sample avalible at https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-aspnet-sample

Comment: Neither of them are WP7 samples?